# Phrase for stage or step after "square one"?

Tags: expressions

"Square Two" would seem natural, but
not sure I've ever heard anyone say that ...

Comment: I can never seem to get past square one.  Maybe there isn't anything else!

Comment: Please expand the question to make it clearer.

Comment: What is the context in which one would want to use *square two*? Unless one is speaking literally about a board game that involves numbered squares, *square one* is used only within the idiom *going back to square one*.

Answer (score 2):

The Oxford English Dictionary Online posits that the origins of "square one" are from games "involving counters or numbered squares, such as hopscotch or Snakes and Ladders."
https://web.archive.org/web/20060316094439/http://www.oed.com/bbcwords/square-new.html

In such games going back to "square one" is a significant loss, while progressing to the second "square" isn't that notable. Similarly, the usage of "square one" may be colloquially so connected to starting something or returning to the starting point that there is no corresponding phrase for the next step – you are either at "square one" or you are beyond it or you have returned to it.

Comment: But did you pass GO and collect $200?

Comment: Hi tevyk, welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but you haven't provided any supporting evidence to differentiate a good answer from unsubstantiated personal opinion. NB: an answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *square one* (linked to the source) and say why it explains your point. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)